An interesting battery problem about graph theory?
Alice's TV remote needs two warking batteries to function. She finds eight batteries in her drawer, and remember that four of them work, and four of them do not, but there is no way of telling them apart without testing them in the remote. Alice wants to find two working batteries to use her TV remote. What is the minimum number of tests that will suffice even in
the worst case?
I have found a method that needs only 6 tests, but how to prove 6 tests are necessary? Moreover, what is the relation between this problem and graph theory? (This is my homework of graph theory.)

What does this have to do with graph theory? Well… HINT: What things might make sense as vertices, and what might be a sensible reason for creating an edge between any two of them?
